# Postgres hstore in rails- How to sum all values of multiple records with the same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.2, hstore

In a rails find...how do I sum all the values from multiple records that have a matching key?

For example, I have a flight and duty log where users store times they have flown or worked. I am storing these k/v pairs using hstore.  One duty log will be created each day.  If a user logs time in the same aircraft day after day...I need to be able to do something like this:

```
  Dutylog.where(user_id: current_user).where("(properties -> '206B')::float > 0.0")
        # properties is the hstore hash
```

This finds all the correct records...but, I am having trouble summing all the values whos key is "206B".

How would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its in the docs...but the docs are not easy to understand...at least for me.  Here is a solution:

```
 Dutylog.where("(properties -> '206B')::float > 0.0").sum("(properties -> '206B')::float")
```